# How can I record using two USB microphones at same time?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, usb, podcasts

Trying to start a podcast and I want to record it using two different USB microphones. I can only get Windows to recognize one mic at a time. What program can I use to make this work?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sound.SE. Please take a moment to read the [help section on asking good questions](http://sound.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). As it currently stands your question lacks a lot of details. What is the program you're using to record the mic's for example? What is the brand and type of the mic? Please make your question more specific by adding details to it (using the [edit](http://sound.stackexchange.com/posts/28112/edit) button).

Comment: Next time please search for previous answers - question is already answered here: [Monitoring multiple USB microphones](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23849/monitoring-multiple-usb-microphones)